# How does Apple know that I called Apple from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, privacy, call

I called Apple from France at 0805 540 003. The robot said: “I see that you are calling from an iPhone. Are you calling about this iPhone?” Indeed, I was calling from an iPhone. How does the robot know that?

This is suspect.

Comment: Is the phone number you called from registered with your Apple ID?

Comment: Or did the call go via Facetime?

Comment: Did you tried to call this number hiding your mobile number ? This can show if iPhone recognition comes from mobile number.

Answer (score 3):

I can also only speculate about the reasons, but there are two things I can come up with:

1. you have probably enabled iMessage. In order to use this service effectively, when someone sends you a message via the iOS Messages App, Apple needs to determine if you are online, then you will receive the message as an iMessage, otherwise it will be send over some mobile carrier. As the end user receiving the message there is no difference recognizable, only as the sending user you are told that the message is sent as an SMS, as you will probably be charged by your mobile carrier for it.
   Therefore Apple has your mobile phone number stored in some kind of database, and will be able to see that you are calling from an iPhone.
2. In contrast to the old times of analogue telephony, today’s calls are almost always transmitted via Voice over IP. And in the headers of IP packages there are multiple variables in which information about the packet sending device are stored and transmitted. Therefore the receiving server knows how to „encode“ the message it wants to return. By this Apple could also determine from what kind of device you are calling.

Please keep in mind that I am in no kind an Apple employee or something, so my answer is only some „targeted guessing“ based on what I know has to go on in the background during calls and text messages.

Answer (score -3):

I have a theory that it may be related to the IMEI.

According to [What is the Difference Between IMEI, IMSI, ICCID, and MSISDN Numbers?](https://www.efani.com/blog/difference-between-imei-imsi-iccid-and-msisdn-numbers)

> IMEI numbers contain information on the phone's model, origin, and serial number, among other things.

You can identify the model of the phone, and the mobile carrier has access to it.

However, according to [What is MSISDN and How does it work?](https://www.telesign.com/glossary/what-is-msisdn)

> When a user makes a call or sends a message, the MSISDN is used by the mobile network to identify the mobile device and route the call or message to the correct destination. The MSISDN is stored in the Home Location Register (HLR) and Visitor Location Register (VLR) of the mobile network operator.

GSM communication is done through other identifiers.

In the other hand, according to [Oracle® Communications Diameter Signaling Router Equipment Identity Register User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E93177_01/docs.83/EIR/GUID-795E4549-608A-4A7A-BDC5-A7E8248D2ACD.htm)

> The Equipment Identity Register (EIR) is a network entity used in GSM networks that stores lists of International Mobile Equipment Identity (IMEI) numbers, which correspond to physical handsets (not subscribers). The IMEI is used to identify the actual handset and is not dependent upon the International Mobile Subscriber Identity (IMSI), Mobile Station ISDN Number (MSISDN), or the Subscriber Identity Module (SIM). The IMSI, MSISDN, and SIM are all subscriber-specific and move with the subscriber when purchasing a new handset. The IMEI is handset-specific.

There is an EIR database that collects IMEI numbers.

I also decided to [ask ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/share/6386aa0a-d721-43f5-8c9f-3535c8187c6f) what it know about it.

> No, IVR (Interactive Voice Response) systems typically do not have access to the IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity) of the caller.

However, I found a company that provides services in the field of telecommunications - software and hardware - PROTEI. They have access to technology (including IVR and call center) that can be put together so maybe Apple uses a similar identification system. They know every iDevice's EMEI they have ever produced.